# open: redirecting doesn't work when using an array as an argument?

Tags: perl

```
my $cmd = "$exe build 2>&1 </dev/null";
my $FH = FileHandle->new;
open $FH, '-|', $cmd
    or die "cannot open: $!";
close $FH;
```

Now when I changed $cmd to an array

```
my @cmd = ($exe, 'fly', '2>&1', '</dev/null');
```

it seems to ignore `'2>&1`' and `'</dev/null'`

How can I preserve redirecting STDIN and STDERR using an array an argument to `open`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mode that you're attempting to use, `open FILEHANDLE, MODE, EXPR, LIST` has the following notes:

> In the form of pipe opens taking three or more arguments, if LIST is specified (extra arguments after the command name) then LIST becomes arguments to the command invoked if the platform supports it.

However, redirection with `2>&1` and `</dev/null` are *shell constructs*, not *arguments*.

If you must go the array route, you'll need to use `join` to reassemble your array elements to fit the standard `open FILEHANDLE, MODE, EXPR` mode.

```
open $FH, q{-|}, join(' ', @cmd)
```

**Note:** If you're using an array to avoid shell interpolation of `$exe`, then you should consider using [@Sobrique's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30105306/477563) using `IPC::Open3` instead.

Comment: You than have to properly backslash/quote the parameters, though.

Comment: One of the primary reasons to use the LIST form of open is to *avoid* the security ramifications/complications of involving the shell.  The `open3` solution is probably more responsible.

Comment: This is very bad advice. If you wanted to build a shell command, it would look something like `use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote ); shell_quote($exe, 'fly') . ' </dev/null 2>&1'`.

Answer (score 4):

As already indicated in another answer - `2>&1` and `</dev/null` aren't arguments in the same sense, which is why they don't work.

However in terms of `STDIN` and `STDERR` you may wish to consider `IPC::Open2` or [`IPC::Open3`](http://search.cpan.org/~shay/perl-5.20.2/ext/IPC-Open3/lib/IPC/Open3.pm) - that way you don't have to worry about it.

```
use IPC::Open3;
$pid = open3(my $exe_stdin, my $exe_stdout, my $exec_stderr,
                'some cmd and args', 'optarg', ...);
```

That way you can just `close $exe_stdin` to get the same result as redirecting `/dev/null` and you can read the other streams independently.

Comment: Re "you can read the other streams independently", not with the syntax you used. You actually did the equivalent of `2>&1`. And it would be really really hard to do. If you need to read STDOUT and STDERR independently, use IPC::Run3 or IPC::Run.

Answer (score 3):

When there's only one argument, it's treated as a shell command.

When there's more than one, it's treated as a program to execute and arguments to that program.

That means that `2>&1` you used to pass to the shell is now being passed as an argument to the program.

This is easy to demonstrate with `system`, which uses the same convention.

```
$ perl -e'system(q{perl -E'\''say for @ARGV'\'' abc 2>&1})'
abc

$ perl -e'system(q{perl}, q{-E}, q{say for @ARGV}, q{abc}, q{2>&1})'
abc
2>&1
```

---

Since

```
my $full_cmd = "$exe build 2>&1 </dev/null";
```

is equivalent to

```
my @full_cmd = ('sh', '-c', "$exe build 2>&1 </dev/null");
```

then we want

```
my @cmd = ($exe, 'build');
my @full_cmd = ('sh', '-c', '"$@" </dev/null', '-', @cmd);
```

if we want to start with the non-shell parts.

---

In context, that means changing

```
my $cmd = "$exe build 2>&1 </dev/null";
open(my $FH, '-|', $cmd)
   or die("Can't launch $exe: $!\n");
```

to

```
my @cmd = ($exe, 'build');
open(my $FH, '-|', 'sh', '-c', '"$@" 2>&1 </dev/null', '-', @cmd)
   or die("Can't launch $cmd[0]: $!\n");
```

Note that you could also use the following:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my @cmd = ($exe, 'build');
open(my $FH, '-|', shell_quote(@cmd).' 2>&1 </dev/null')
   or die("Can't launch $cmd[0]: $!\n");
```